# How to get value from combobox using substring in C# 

Tags: c#, combobox

I have a combo box which have item strings like:

```
1 .  Apple
2 .  Banana
3 .  Mango
```

1,2,3 are category id & Apple, Banana, Mango is Category Name.

I want to know Category Id From comboBox using Category name which is sub-string of ComboBox item.

example:

I want to know the Category Id of Banana. which is 2.

Any help ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: is that work for you ?i.e my answer ?

Comment: Thanks to all of you especially Pranay Rana Your answer is really useful.
that is my first forum & second question this forum is really so active.

Comment: -1 for unclear question. you should write your question clearly and complete. like what you commented on Schaliasos's answer

Comment: @hamed thanks next time i will explain completely **Insha Alah**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    foreach (object item in cmb.Items)
    {
      string[] str = item.ToString().split(new char[] {' '}
, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
      if(str[1] == "Banana")
      {
           Console.Write(str[0]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: There is 3 space between category ID and category name.it should be str[str.count-1] == "Bannana"

Comment: @hamed - that y i added StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries in my spilt function as parameter so it remove null entries..read the documenttation of split that will give you more idea

Answer (score 4):

Use this code to an event that should be after you selected the item in comboBox :

```
        string []str;
        str = comboBox1.Text.Split(' ');
        string categoryId = str[0];
```

Comment: becuse how i get to know str[0] is related to Banana  or Apple or someother string...answer is incomplete

Comment: @PranayRana I thought he wants to fetch the ID of category after selecting it on comboBox.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code. It will give the `CategotyId` of the selected Category.

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    string selectedText = comboBox1.SelectedText;
    string categoryId  = selectedText.Substring(0, selectedText.IndexOf(" "));

    MesasgeBox.Show(categoryId);
}
```

Comment: i am not selecting any index of combobox & not selectedIndexChanged method is called.
Combo box is filled with values & now i am selecting these strings like Mango from grid box instead of again fetching category id from data base which is costly in term of processing cost i wants to take  that value from combobox which is already filled & much faster.
thanks For Answer

Comment: The point of my answer is to use the `Substring` method. You can use it in any method you want. I don't understand the reason of downvoting.

Comment: i did not downvoted for you. Your answer was helpful really thanks Schaliasos.

Comment: Pranay Rana downvoted you. the reason is as what is he commented on my answer

Answer (score 2):

@Pranay Rana Your Answer Helped me:
I wrote my method like that

```
private string get_Godown_id(string godown_name)
    {
        foreach (object item in cb_send_to.Items)
        {
            if (item.ToString().Split('.')[1].Trim() == godown_name)
            {
                return (item.ToString().Split('.')[0]);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (object item in cb_send_to.Items)
    {
        if (item.ToString().Split('.')[1].Trim() == godown_name)
        {
            return (item.ToString().Split('.')[0]);
        }
    }
```